# init() method in servlet

Tags: servlets, methods, init

can we change the name of the init() method of servlet?
i mean to say the life should be-
xyz()-service()-destroy()
instead of 
init()-service()-destroy()

Answer (score 11):

No. `init()` is a method defined in the servlet base class - if you use a different method name, you won't be overriding an existing method.

You could write an `init()` method which just calls `xyz()` of course - and do so in a base class used by all your servlets. It doesn't seem like a great idea though - why would you want to do this in the first place?